# What is the purpose of the sa_data field in a sockaddr?

Tags: c, sockets, struct, network-programming, bind

```
int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

The actual structure passed for the addr argument will depend on the address family. The sockaddr structure is defined as something like:

```
struct sockaddr {
    sa_family_t sa_family;
    char        sa_data[14];
}
```

So for an IPv4 address (AF_INET), the actual struct that will be passed is this:

```
/* Source http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip */

struct sockaddr_in {
    sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
    in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
    struct in_addr sin_addr;   /* internet address */
};

/* Internet address. */
struct in_addr {
    uint32_t       s_addr;     /* address in network byte order */
};
```

Does the bind code read the `sockaddr.sa_family` value and depending on the value it finds, it will then cast the `sockaddr` struct into the appropriate struct such as `sockaddr_in`?

Why is the `sa_data` set to 14 characters?  If I understand correct, the `sa_data` field is just a field that will have large enough memory space to fit all address family types?  Presumably the original designers anticipated that 14 characters would be wide enough to fit all future types.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [glibc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Address-Formats.html):

> The length 14 of sa_data is essentially arbitrary.

And the [FreeBSD developers handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/sockets-essential-functions.html) mentions the following:

> Please note the vagueness with which the sa_data field is declared,
>   just as an array of 14 bytes, with the comment hinting there can be
>   more than 14 of them.
>
> **This vagueness is quite deliberate.** Sockets is a very powerful
>   interface. While most people perhaps think of it as nothing more than
>   the Internet interface—and most applications probably use it for that
>   nowadays—sockets can be used for just about any kind of interprocess
>   communications, of which the Internet (or, more precisely, IP) is only
>   one.

Yes, the `sa_family` field is used to recognize how to treat the struct passed (which is cast to `struct sockaddr*` in a call to bind). You can read more about how it works also in a [FreeBSD developers handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/sockets-essential-functions.html).

And actually there are "polymorphic" (sub)types of `sockaddr`, in which `sa_data` contains more than 16 bytes, for example:

```
struct sockaddr_un {
    sa_family_t sun_family;               /* AF_UNIX */
    char        sun_path[108];            /* pathname */
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The `sockaddr` struct is used as a tagged union. By reading the `sa_family` field it can be cast to a struct of the proper form.

The 14 bytes is arbitrary. It's big enough to hold IPv4 addresses, but not big enough to hold IPv6 addresses. There is also a `sockaddr_storage` struct which is big enough for both. Reading the Microsoft docs on [SOCKADDR_STORAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff570825(v=vs.85).aspx), it comes in at 128 bytes, so much larger than needed for IPv6. Checking some Linux headers, it seems to be at least that large there as well.

For reference, the IPv6 struct is:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 {
    u_int16_t       sin6_family;   // address family, AF_INET6
    u_int16_t       sin6_port;     // port number, Network Byte Order
    u_int32_t       sin6_flowinfo; // IPv6 flow information
    struct in6_addr sin6_addr;     // IPv6 address
    u_int32_t       sin6_scope_id; // Scope ID
};

struct in6_addr {
    unsigned char   s6_addr[16];   // IPv6 address
};
```

As you can see, the 16 byte `s6_addr` field is already bigger than the 14 byte `sa_data` field on it's own. Total size after the `sa_family` field is 26 bytes.